# Terraform resource with this ID doesn't exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to import the existing s3 bucket to my terraform using the below commands

```
$ terraform import aws_s3_bucket.test-bucket test-bucket200
```

Here is my code:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "test-bucket" {
  bucket = "test-bucket200"
}   

resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "test-bucket-acl" {
  bucket = "${aws_s3_bucket.test-bucket.id}"

  block_public_acls   = false
  block_public_policy = false
  
}
```

While importing `aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block` (after the bucket import) throwing me the error

```
$ terraform import aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block.test-bucket-acl test-bucket200
```

`Terraform detected a resource with this ID doesn't exist. Please verify the ID is correct. You cannot import non-existent.resources using Terraform import.`

However my state shows

```
$ terraform state show
id                                     = test-bucket200
arn                                    = arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket200
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is this due to the older version?

```
$ terraform version
Terraform v0.11.13
+ provider.aws v2.10.0
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: The error indicates that bucket does not exist where you are trying to read it. Also, if the bucket is already in your state, then you do not need to `import` it.

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong here? Is this due to the older version?

I don't think its due to older version. I just tried to **replicate** the issue with `v0.11.13` and  `v2.10.0` but had **no issues**.

```
./terraform import aws_s3_bucket.test-bucket test-bucket2003333                                                                                                                                           
aws_s3_bucket.test-bucket: Importing from ID "test-bucket2003333"...                                                                                                                                                        
aws_s3_bucket.test-bucket: Import complete!                                                                                                                                                                                 
  Imported aws_s3_bucket (ID: test-bucket2003333)                                                                                                                                                                           
aws_s3_bucket.test-bucket: Refreshing state... (ID: test-bucket2003333)                                                                                                                                                     

Import successful!

The resources that were imported are shown above. These resources are now in
your Terraform state and will henceforth be managed by Terraform.
```

and

```
./terraform import aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block.test-bucket-acl test-bucket2003333
aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block.test-bucket-acl: Importing from ID "test-bucket2003333"...
aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block.test-bucket-acl: Import complete!
  Imported aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block (ID: test-bucket2003333)
aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block.test-bucket-acl: Refreshing state... (ID: test-bucket2003333)

Import successful!

The resources that were imported are shown above. These resources are now in
your Terraform state and will henceforth be managed by Terraform.
```

Your commands seems fine. It appears something else is happening, not apparent from your question.